# Blocking a country IP using php

Tags: php

So i have the following code :

```
        $ip = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP') ?: getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR') ?: getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED') ?: getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR') ?: getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED') ?: getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
        $details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/$ip/json"));

    if ($details->country == US):
    {
       echo "We are sorry, We cannot allow users from United States";
       die();
    }
    elseif ($details->country == GB):
    {
       echo "We are sorry, We cannot allow users from United Kingdom";
       die();
{
else:
show index script
```

The problem is , some US and  UK users can still see the index

Comment: Maybe the IP isn't correctly listed in the json file?

Comment: or they use a vpn or proxy or a lot other ways to fake the ip address

Comment: manually checked the IP's and they was from US and GB

Comment: Or if the headers aren't stripped/removed by any reverse proxy / load balancer they could simply supply a different IP in Client-IP: or X-Forwarded-For:.

Comment: btw - it should be `"US"` and `"GB"`

Comment: The user from GB is a friend he dosent use a proxy or modify anything.

Comment: @Philipp I will try it

Comment: @Philipp nice catch, still i think we are in front of a X/Y problem.

Comment: This question answer is partial. IP addresses can be blocked using PHP but if the user uses a third party application for VPN or something the banned users will be able to access the content or whatever the data is.

Comment: show us a var_dump($details->country) please

Comment: @Melvita the output is "NULL".... but if i use print_r($details->country) I'm getting the Country name of ip

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are comparing to a constant named US or GB. You probably want to check for the string.

`$details->country === 'US'`.

Comment: Still not working. I tried if ($details->country == 'GB'): and if ($details->country == "GB"): and if ($details->country === 'GB'):

Comment: Well as stated above you need to make sure you are retrieving your visitors ip correctly. So its an x/y problem.

Comment: {
  "ip": "159.2*.*.*",
  "city": "****",
  "region": "Connecticut",
  "country": "US",
  "loc": "41.0610,-73.5429",
  "org": "AS24012 TR-IP-ADMIN",
  "postal": ""
}   The output of $details->country is  US

Comment: Is there anything else that might be relevant in your script? I just checked it with my IP and the snippet works fine.

Comment: The script is located in index.php of the laravel framework after require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
 and $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

Comment: Well, at that point I am almost certain your request variables are not even set up. You are probably best off using Middleware and reading up the fundamentals first. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware

Answer (score -1):

The problem was at http://ipinfo.io/$ip/json i get  Rate limit exceeded error.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how was checking the raw response not your first step in debugging?

Comment: I didnt know they have an IP check limit. So it worked before.